# How to run Xbox One ADK with command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, xbox-one

After installed `XboxOneADK,` there will be a Xbox One ADK Command Prompt.

**its target is below:**

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Durango XDK\adk\DurangoVars.cmd" ADK
```

**Then it can run as a new cmd window. And I can run command in this cmd window.**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Durango XDK\bin>xbapp.exe xxxxxx
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Durango XDK\bin>Makepkg.exe xxxxxx
...
```

I dont't like it's too manual.

How can I run only one command to launch the ADK cmd window with xbapp.exe and Makepkg.exe commands?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prepare a text file with this contents:

**example.txt**:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Durango XDK\adk\DurangoVars.cmd" ADK
xbapp.exe xxxxxx
Makepkg.exe xxxxxx
...
exit
```

And "execute it" this way:

```
cmd < example.txt
```